# Drupal's Aggregate Javascript breaks CKEditor Config

Tags: drupal, ckeditor, javascript

With Aggregate Javascript turned on under Administration » Configuration » Development » Performance, Civi's Configure CKEditor page doesn't display the editor's container or configurator.

Drupal 7.41/Civi 4.7

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, that was a bug. I poked around and found a spot for the js that doesn't break under aggregation:

https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/7711